# Convert ODBC Canonical date to binary, or using a ODBC Canonical function

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I have a query where I am trying to pull information where the firstdate is less than the seconddate, however most date times are pretty close to each other, so I tried:

```
select id from entries where firstdate [less than] seconddate -2000000000
```

However it doesn't seem to provide the information I would like. I have two thoughts:

1. I could convert the ODBC Canonical dates to binary so I can use a variable like in the example above.
2. Use a ODBC Canonical function where I could simply state that the second date is at least 10 days behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
firstdate < DATE_ADD(seconddate, INTERVAL -10 DAY)
```

**EDIT:**

In your case will be:

```
select id from entries where firstdate < DATE_ADD(seconddate, INTERVAL -10 DAY)
```